# How can I access Android's Barcode Scanner from WebView?

Tags: android, barcode

I love the BarCode Scanner application for the Android phone; We're using Motorola's Droid.

Is it possible to access the BarCode Scanner from a web application running on the phone? I was thinking of using a WebView, but I'm not sure how I'd access the Scanner API.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize it using `Intent`s. The contract is [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java).
Should probably add a custom Javascript handler to the `WebView` in order to fire an `Intent` and parse the result.

Answer (score 0):

Developer here. The answer is yes and no. At the moment, yes, you can see this working if you go to Google Product Search on Android. You'll see a scan barcode button which launches Barcode Scanner -- apps can respond to URLs clicked in the browser, yes.

Barcode Scanner is hard-coded to respond after scanning by sending you to a product result page from Google Product Search. So at the moment, no, it can't be made to redirect you anywhere else.

But, this week a [change](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=370) was checked in to allow you to do exactly this. It'll be available in an upcoming Barcode Scanner version.